# How can I check if two regular expressions are the same?

Tags: javascript, regex, equality

If JavaScript, `/\.scss$/` is a regex.  I want to check whether a regex is exactly the same as another regex, however:

```
/\.scss$/ === /\.scss$/ // false
```

How can I do this?  Note that I do not care about what the regex matches, I only care about the way the regex is defined.

Comment: `typeof /\.scss$/` is `"object"` and two objects cannot be compared using equality operators.

Answer (score 6):

Use `.toString`:

```
/\.scss$/.toString() === /\.scss$/.toString() // true
```

It's easier to see what is going on when using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object:

```
new RegExp("ab+c").toString() === new RegExp("ab+c").toString() // true
```

whereas

```
new RegExp("ab+c") === new RegExp("ab+c") // false
```

Comment: `new RegExp("ab+c") === new RegExp("ab+c")` is `false` because both are objects and `===` cannot compare objects.

Comment: The two regex `aa` and `a{2}` are same, how these can be compared? `toString()` will fail here.

Comment: @Tushar I have clarified in the question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about using **source** attribute?

```
/\.scss$/.source === /\.scss$/.source && /\.scss$/.flags === /\.scss$/.flags
```

It's faster then using **toString** function.
http://jsperf.com/source-vs-tostring

[image]

Comment: This works for regexps with no flags, but `source` does not contain the flag information:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source

Comment: then I add `&& /\.scss$/.flags === /\.scss$/.flags`